# How to render a page on a WordPress website for a subdomain using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a website that has multiple subdomains like country1.example.com, country2.example.com etc. I am developing this website in WordPress and want to map the subdomains with particular pages. For example for a subdomain `india.example.com` I want to render `example.com/countries/india`

for this I have done following but it is not working for all subdomains it is showing same hone page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.exapmle.com
RewriteRule (.*)  countries/%1
```

How can I do this using htaccess as I am not at all aware of htaccess programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/countries/%1/$1 [L]
```

It will also redirect india.example.com/test.html to www.example.com/india/test.html